# CoreBluetooth on iPhone 5C/5S: broken received data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I've got a strange problem using CoreBluetooth on iPhone 5C & iPhone 5S.
By scenario, I'm going to receive 83 bytes of data, chunked by 20 bytes (5 chunks in common).
And data are differs on iPhone 5S/5C (please see the dump below): chunk #4 substitutes chunk #3 under these devices.
But on iPad3 (with the 6.1 & 7.0.2 iOS) all is OK

```
// iPhone 5C, iOS 7.0.2
nRF UART[237:60b] Received data on a characteristic. 0x01=001,0x02=5B2226
nRF UART[237:60b] Received data on a characteristic. 400192,0x05=1.0.0,0x
nRF UART[237:60b] Received data on a characteristic. ,0x09=2,0x0a=0,0x0b=
nRF UART[237:60b] Received data on a characteristic. ,0x09=2,0x0a=0,0x0b=
nRF UART[237:60b] Received data on a characteristic. 100ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ

// iPad 3, iOS 6.1.3 && iPad 3, iOS 7.0.2
nRF UART[221:60b] Received data on a characteristic. 0x01=001,0x02=5B2226
nRF UART[221:60b] Received data on a characteristic. 400192,0x05=1.0.0,0x
nRF UART[221:60b] Received data on a characteristic. 07=2013.010,0x08=001
nRF UART[221:60b] Received data on a characteristic. ,0x09=2,0x0a=0,0x0b=
nRF UART[221:60b] Received data on a characteristic. 100ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ

// iPhone 4S, iOS 6.1.3
nRF UART[241:60b] Received data on a characteristic. 0x01=001,0x02=5B2226
nRF UART[241:60b] Received data on a characteristic. 400192,0x05=1.0.0,0x
nRF UART[241:60b] Received data on a characteristic. 07=2013.010,0x08=001
nRF UART[241:60b] Received data on a characteristic. ,0x09=2,0x0a=0,0x0b=
nRF UART[241:60b] Received data on a characteristic. 100ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ
```

My question is: how to get a normal data from 5S/5C devices? Perhaps, there are some tricks with CBCharacteristic or CBCentralManager?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

As **@allprog** suggested, here is the fragments of the code how I'm using CoreBluetooth.

This is the pretty basic approach:

```
// CBCentralManager init
self.cm = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

// Getting data chunks from CBCharacteristic in CBPeripheral's Delegate
- (void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
    {
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error receiving notification for characteristic %@: %@", characteristic, error);
    return;
        }

        NSLog(@"Received data on a characteristic. %s", [[characteristic value] bytes]);
        // ... the rest of code
}
```

Comment: Also, have you tried to reduce the speed of data sending? Is this a consistent error or happens only sometimes? If you use notifications, then those can get lost. Use a dedicated queue for initializing the CBCentralManager to avoid overloading the main queue. Can you show the parts of the code that handle the data reception? Alternatively, change to using indications. They are slower but reliable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're transferring large chunks of data and have to split it up over multiple packets, I would recommend adding some sort of ID to each packet. This will give you the additional information you need on the receiving side to determine whether a packet was dropped, received twice, etc. If you detect a packet was dropped, you'll likely want a way to re-request a packet by ID from the peripheral.

Edit: also, as mentioned in the comments, you can switch to indications to let the Bluetooth stack take care of your needs for guaranteed and non-duplicated delivery.

Comment: I was ended up with this problem by modifying the firmware of an Arduino Board which I'm using for development. So the problem was in the case when Arduino send the packets back to my iOS App with the little delay between each packet (it was 15 ms). I've increased this delay to 30 ms and the issue disappeared. Strangely that the issue is raised up only on modern devices (5C & 5S phones). It doesn't depend to iOS version. I've tested also on iPad 3 & iPhone 4S with 6.1 & 7.0.2: all of 'old' devices were fine to process data in usual manner.